# How to Bind Data Of angular-Charts Dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, charts, angularjs-controller

I am using [`angular-charts`](http://chinmaymk.github.io/angular-charts/) directives in my application and it works well when we set the data initially.But when i read the data from json file and assign the data to the chart, it just generates x axis and y axis but not the legends.Here is my code,

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="content" ng-controller="MainCtrl1" class="box-content">   
    <div style="position:relative">
     <div  data-ac-chart="'bar'"    data-ac-data="widget.data"  data-ac-config="config"  class="chart"> 
     </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the model where i read the data from a file,

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
               <div  >
              <input type="file" on-read-file="showContent($fileContent)" />
         </div>
  </div>
```

**App.JS:**

```
  $scope.data = {
     "series": ["Northern", "Western", "Southern", "East", "Center"],
     "data": [ {
      "x": "Mahinda",
      "y": [90, 800, 600,100,900]
    }, {
      "x": "Maithiri",
      "y": [351,439,380,800,300]
    }, {
     "x": "Others",
     "y": [140, 33,230, 879,43]
   }]
 };
```

Here am assigning the data to the widget,

```
$scope.addBarChart = function() {
  $scope.dashboard.widgets.push({
    name: "General election",
    sizeX: 110,
    sizeY: 50,
    type:"Bar",
    data:$scope.data
  });
};
```

This works well, and this is the output.
[image]

Then am reading the data from a json file and assigning to the data object of widget,

```
  $scope.showContent = function($fileContent){
        $scope.widget.data = $fileContent;
    };
```

Here is the output:

[image]

There is no errors on the console as well.

Comment: try adding if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();

Comment: show your ajax code.it should either use $http or $resource

Comment: @pankajparkar no i just get the data from a json file using a file picker

Comment: how are you fetching that data?

Comment: @pankajparkar I have modified the question by including the code from where i read the json file

Comment: did you try to add if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply(); after receiving data?

Comment: @pankajparkar yes i tried now, it also dint work. thanks for your time bro

Comment: put console.log($scope.widget.data) in $scope.showContent after assigning data

Comment: Ya data gets printed, only the problem is the changes does not reflect in the chart

Comment: I spent some time on it, and finally i found the solution. Answser has been added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68626/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem solution is very simple.

The fileContent which you are getting using "on-read-file" directive, it returns the fileContent in string format.
anguar-charts data property shpuld always be in JSON format
Only you need to do JSON.parse() recieved $fileContent to JSON.

**Code**

```
$scope.showContent = function($fileContent) {
    $scope.widget.data = JSON.parse($fileContent);;
};
```

I created a test.txt file for test and wrote the below code inside it.

**test.txt**

```
{
     "series": ["Northern", "Western", "Southern", "East", "Center"],
     "data": [ {
      "x": "Mahinda",
      "y": [90, 800, 600,100,900]
    }, {
      "x": "Maithiri",
      "y": [351,439,380,800,300]
    }, {
     "x": "Others",
     "y": [140, 33,230, 879,43]
   }]
 }
```

You can refer [fiddle link](http://plnkr.co/edit/pmTVdJ?p=preview) for more info.
Hopefully this will be pretty helpful to you.

Comment: It works in fiddler, does not work with my project.is it necessary to parse into Json since i already have Json file

Comment: yes..because the directive is returning a data in string format.anyhow you need to parse it to get actual JSON

Comment: in fiddle i've used $scpe.data you should replace it with $scope.widget.data

Answer (score 0):

Try adding $scope.$apply(); after $scope.widget.data = $fileContent;